# Do bombs, arrow volleys, warhammers and such affect my soldiers too?

Tags: bad-north

Title pretty much says it all: do these "per-tile" actions also cause damage to my soldiers, or just the enemy soldiers?

Some times it looks like a bomb blew up 3 of my soldiers, but then other times they appear unaffected... is it just coincidence, or is there friendly-fire at play?

Answer (score 2):

Bombs and mines kill your own soldiers.
Arrow volleys (or normal arrows) do not have an effect.
Warhammer pushes your own soldiers away but does not seem to hurt them (unless they fly off the map).